# Rotate sprite opposite of phone rotation with cocos2d?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to rotate a sprite exactly the opposite of phone rotation so that the sprite stays upright relative to the ground, regardless of the position of the phone.

It works for the most part, but the variation in accelerometer readings, no matter how still the phone is, makes the sprite "bouncy". Basically my code is very simple - I just multiply the acceleration reading by -90 whenever I do an accelerometer reading:

```
_pink.rotation = acceleration.y * (-90);
```

This works, but even with the phone sitting on a tablet, it bounces back and forth due to inconsistent accelerometer readings. How can I make it smooth? I am aware of `KFilteringFactor`, which I implemented but it just made the movement slower, so it didnt keep up with the opposite of phone movement. Maybe I was using it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 float angle = angle-90;
[pink setRotation:angle];
```